# Propagating hover events through layers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an interactive background covered by an overlay. When the user hovers over these elements, the hover event is only triggered for the overlay. Is there a way to simultaneously trigger the hover events for both elements?

Comment: We have no idea since we have no clue what your code is.

Comment: You would have to somehow know, perhaps by cursor position, which of the elements "beneath" the overlay is getting hovered. Sounds like a lot of work. Usually one uses an overlay precisely to prevent this behavior. There is likely a different way to achieve what you want, if you care to explain what that is.

Comment: @epascarello In this case I don't think the actual code matters in this case. I was just wondering if there is a way to "link" hover or mouseenter/mouseleave events for 2 elements that are layered.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks, it does seem like it would be difficult to accomplish if there isn't a simple way to achieve this kind of "global" event trigger

Comment: @A.Rahm but how it is laid out matters, how things catch events matters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pointer-events: none;`

```css
#first-div {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

#first-div:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

#second-div {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="first-div"></div>
<div id="second-div"></div>
```